# How to run 'gcc' command from php on the browser with apache web server

Tags: php, gcc

Rookie  @PHP , Objective is to compile the C program from the browser using PHP , google'd and found out the solution is to run the shell_exec command . so the program is working in the shell , but it is not working from the web browser

Code is

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('gcc /home/sam/php_practice/prog.c');
echo "$output";
?>
```

> PS : if we replace 'gcc' with 'ls' it is working in  web browser as
>   well , so what is the differnce i am not able to understand , what i m
>   missing ..

Any thoughts will be appreciated .....

Comment: If the C file hasn't any errors, then compilation is successful and there is no output to be shown. On the contrary ls will display the content of the directory.

Comment: if C file is having error it will be showing in the shell , just pasting the output

Comment: sam@sam:/var/www/html$ php hello.php 
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:6:3: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘return’
   return 0;
   ^

Comment: You need to redirect the error message from stderr to stdout in order for shell_exec to collect the output. Change the line to: 
$output = shell_exec("gcc /home/sam/php_practice/prog.c 2>&1");

Comment: what does that mean 2>&1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redirect the error message from stderr to stdout in order for `shell_exec()` to collect the output. Change the line to:

```
$output = shell_exec("gcc /home/sam/php_practice/prog.c 2>&1");
```

If you need more information about [redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) just follow the link!